# Is there a maximum number of clients Node WS can handle?

Tags: node.js, websocket, server, digital-ocean, ws

I'm using the node ws (Websocket library) to serve video to clients. Eventually I'd be looking to make the website more public and I could not find any documentation in the ws library about how many clients could possibly be supported at any given time. I've had no issues with ~5 because that's my standard use case now but I was curious if I reached 1000+ would node ws bottleneck me or would it come down to the bandwidth and specs of the server itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using WebSockets for video in the first place?

Comment: node-rtsp-stream for restreaming IP camera in a web consumable format.

Comment: It will come down to the bandwidth and specs of the server itself.  Tens, maybe even hundreds of thousands of concurrent webSockets are possible with the right hardware, software and OS configuration.  Serving video though has some more specialized solutions that using webSockets when interested in achieving high scale.